# How do you make the FlatList scroll inherently?

Tags: javascript, react-native

```
import React from 'react';
import {FlatList, Text, Button, ScrollView, View, ListView} from 'react-native';
import axios from 'axios';
class ChatList extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { data:[], refreshing:false};

  }

  async componentDidMount(){
    this._getChatList();
    console.log("Received Data")
  }

  _getChatList(){
    axios.get('http://10.0.2.2:5000/app_log')
     .then((response) =>  { this.setState({ data: response.data.data}); console.log(response.data)})
     .catch((error)=>{console.log("Api call error");alert(error.message);});


     console.log(this.state);
  }


  _keyExtractor (item, index) {
    return index.toString();
  }

  render() {
    return(

     <FlatList
        data={this.state.data}
        keyExtractor={this._keyExtractor.bind(this)}
        renderItem={({item}) => (<Text>{item.message} FROM {item.sender} </Text>)}
        extraData={this.state}
        horizontal={false}
      />
    );
  }
}
export default ChatList;
```

I've tried putting this component in a ScrollView and it gives a warning, but other similar questions make it seem like it should just scroll without any modification. I'm not really sure what I'm doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to set a style to the flatlist in order to limit its height and prevent it grows while items are added. The simplest way would be to set the style to fill the available space like:

```
     <FlatList
        style={{ flex: 1 }}
        ...
      />
```

Once the Flatlist content reach that limit, stops growing and you'll be able to scroll.

Since Flatlist has a scrollview internally, is not a common use case to wrap a flatlist inside a scrollview.

Cheers!